# Как изменить шрифт через <select>?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Имеется **HTML** примерно с таким кодом

```html
<label class="select">Выберите шрифт</label>
<select id="font" class="select">
  <option style="color: white; font-family: comic sans ms" value="comic sans ms">Comic Sans MS</option>
  <option style="color: white; font-family: segoe script" value="segoe script">Segoe Script</option>
</select>
```

Мне надо сделать так, что-бы при выборе одного из этих вариантов менялся шрифт в CSS классе `.select`

Ну или значение CSS переменной (я только недавно начал заниматься `ВЕБ-ом`, поэтому вообще не шарю ни в `CSS`, ни в `HTML`, ни в `JavaScript`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно таким образом (см. комментарии):

```js
// отслеживаем изменение поля select
font.onchange = function() {

  // Получаем значение выбранного поля
  var selected = font.value;

  // Получаем элемент, в котором будем менять шрифт.
  var change = document.getElementsByClassName('select');

  // Меняем шрифт на полученный из поля select
  change[0].style.fontFamily = selected;
}
```

```css
.select {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<label class="select">Выберите шрифт</label>
<select id="font" class="select">
  <option style="color: white;"></option>
  <option style="color: white; font-family: comic sans ms" value="comic sans ms">
    Comic Sans MS
  </option>
  <option style="color: white; font-family: segoe script" value="sans-serif">
    sans-serif
  </option>
</select>
```